# Laravel add new email template for resetting password

Tags: laravel, email, templates, passwords, reset

I have two laravel instances connected to an API. Default "password reset" functionality was created for the #1 website but now, I want to add new email templates for the users which are trying to reset their password from the second website.

```
public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token, Closure $callback = null)
{
    $view = $this->emailView;

    return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
        $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

        if (! is_null($callback)) {
            call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
        }
    });
}
```

`$view` logs `auth.emails.password` from auth.php (email template for #1 website)

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

I've added a hidden input to differentiate the users but I don't know how to use that in order to send another email template.. Any idea would be much appreciated!